# Access elements of a multi-dimension np.array from a list of indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How can I access to the elements of a multi-dimension np.array given a list of indices? for example, I have a 2D np.array like `arr= np.array([[10,20,30],[40,50,60]])` and a list of indices like `list_ind = [(0,1), (1,1)]`. The question is that how can I access to arr(list_ind), which is `arr[0,1]=20` and `arr[1,1]=50`? Any idea?

Comment: `arr[[0,1],[1,1]]`, but to be more diagnostic `arr[[0,1],[1,2]]` will produce `[20,60]`.

Answer (score 0):

simply:

```
arr[list_ind]
```

or yet better:

```
arr[tuple(list_ind)]
```

output:

```
array([20, 50])
```